# iOS Pixel-to-Points conversion

Tags: pixel, ios

I am delivering design specifications for an iOS iPhone app, and experience lots of measurement inconsistencies between my project PSD file (which is specified in pixels) and the conversion of it to iOS points. My PSD file is 640x960px @72 ppi. What would be the equivalent size in iOS pt for a 26px text paragraph?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Well, my experience with designing for iOS is that you need to take the font size in pt, divide it by 2 and this is the number you need to input in the code. When designing for @2x, that is. Your density should be 72 ppi, which you already have covered. How big are the inconsistencies?